# Analytics e-commerce tracking only taking last item

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics

I have setup e-commerce tracking that is working pretty well on my site. however if the order contains 2 of the same item ID but different attributes it only takes the last line. So for example the output of an order with 6 items that are the same but different sizes looks like this:

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 'id': '3832', 'name': 'Big Al Poly Cotton Shop Coat', 'sku': '140', 'category': 'Shop Coats', 'price': '31.85', 'quantity': '3'});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 'id': '3832', 'name': 'Big Al Poly Cotton Shop Coat', 'sku': '140', 'category': 'Shop Coats', 'price': '31.85', 'quantity': '2'});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 'id': '3832', 'name': 'Big Al Poly Cotton Shop Coat', 'sku': '140', 'category': 'Shop Coats', 'price': '31.85', 'quantity': '4'});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 'id': '3832', 'name': 'Big Al Poly Cotton Shop Coat', 'sku': '140', 'category': 'Shop Coats', 'price': '31.85', 'quantity': '4'});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 'id': '3832', 'name': 'Big Al Poly Cotton Shop Coat', 'sku': '140', 'category': 'Shop Coats', 'price': '31.85', 'quantity': '4'});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 'id': '3832', 'name': 'Big Al Poly Cotton Shop Coat', 'sku': '140', 'category': 'Shop Coats', 'price': '36.65', 'quantity': '2'});
```

The only line that is recorded by analytics is the last one. If the order has different products ordered everything works fine. It is only when there is multiple attributes ordered of the same product that there is a problem.

This is the php that is generating the strings:

```
   $item_string = '';
    $items_query = tep_db_query("select products_id, products_model, products_name, final_price, products_tax, products_quantity from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " where orders_id = '" . $order_id . "' order by products_name");
    while ($items = tep_db_fetch_array($items_query)) {
        $category_query = tep_db_query("select p2c.categories_id, cd.categories_name from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " p2c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where p2c.products_id = '" . $items['products_id'] . "' AND cd.categories_id = p2c.categories_id AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'");
        $category = tep_db_fetch_array($category_query);

        $item_string .= "ga('ecommerce:addItem', { ";
        $item_string .=  "'id': '" . $order_id . "', 'name': '" . $items['products_name'] . "', 'sku': '" . $items['products_id'] . "', 'category': '" . $category['categories_name'] . "', 'price': '" . number_format(tep_add_tax($items['final_price'], $items['products_tax']), 2) . "', 'quantity': '" . $items['products_quantity'] . "'";
        $item_string .= "}); \n";

    }
```

Comment: Walk us through the logic. Is `$items_query` a table with all products ordered? Then you should `GROUP BY products_id`.

Comment: Yes $items query looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/r3tWBVQ.jpg I just changed SKU to use orders_product_id field instead of just product_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all of your items are using the same SKU. GA tracks e-commerce transactions by SKU. ID should be the same as the transaction ID because it ties items to the same transaction.

Check out the [GA e-commerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce) implementation guide for more info.

If you have multiple items in the cart with the same SKU, you should use the quantity parameter.

Comment: This answer is correct, the ID should be the same (transaction id), and sku should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

GA is having trouble separating items because they all have the same id.

GA is picking up unique line items by the product id. Currently you're passing in the product id for the "parent" product.

If you instead provided unique ids for all children products (with different sizes), GA would be able to easily report that.

You probably have the unique ids somewhere in the database, you'd need to modify the `$items_query` to pass in both the child and parent ids. If you don't have child ids in the database, maybe you can append the size to the product id, to create unique ids for analyses through GA.

Comment: Ah ok. I think it is the SKU field that is the cause. I changed those to be unique to each line.